# image slider with youtube video on light box

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, video, youtube

I am using an image slider and when someone clicks on any of the image, the youtube video needs to pop up as a light box.
My HTML is below:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="slider_wrapper">
<ul id="image_slider">
<li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lbJO8MBCyp4" rel="vidbox" title="Vid1"><img src="img2.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzbGTfoHKeQ" rel="vidbox" title="Vid2"><img src="img4.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ve7p5CqTTIM" rel="vidbox" title="Vid3"><img src="img5.jpg"></a></li>

</ul>                   
<span class="nvgt" id="prev"></span>
<span class="nvgt" id="next"></span>
</div>
    </div>
```

Till the time I don't add the lightbox code (js and css), the slider runs just fine. Please help. If someone has a code for this, please post it. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

First off you cant just use the URL for that specific youtube video you would have to use the embedded code that youtube provides. Something like this...

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/equy_MPJ89g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>)
```

Whether or not iframes will work with lightbox though is a whole different issue.